# Resize hard drive partition

Tags: partitioning

I have installed ubuntu besides Windows XP and it is using only 5.9 GB of total drive space.

I would like to know how to increase the size?

Comment: Please research your subject before asking. Your question, appear, to be about partitioning which there is a great deal to read about already. If that isn't your issue please be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and i have already done my part of research and couldn't find a better solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can unmount your hard drive using an external USB drive which would allow you to alter your partition.  The USB drive would have a burned iso of Gparted allowing you to resize the partition yourself.

Comment: Is this really an answer?